# What's a better select/target concept within the scope of js/php

Tags: java, php, html

My problem with this code is on the second click it desellects everything and does not select a particular item. I know it's because of the `item_'.$x.'Active` where even if I have a `selectorReset()` function it does not necessarily reset the value of each individual active back to `0`.

I am aware that this is poor coding, could someone enlighten me with a better solution to having this kind of function? ^_^

example: click item 0 then click item `1` (it works fine as intended)
but if i go back to click to item 0 the activator is set at `1` which means the `else` in function selector will activate with the reset function so nothing is selected.
Question: How do I keep it selected?
Solution: a janky way of solving it hahha or could someone suggest a an already known concept? thanks ^_^

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="area">
    <?php
        $x=0;
        while($x!=10){
            echo'
                <div id="item_'.$x.'" class="area__item" onclick="selector'.$x.'()">
                '.$x.'
                </div>
                <script>
                    var item_'.$x.'Active = 0;
                    var item_'.$x.' = document.getElementById("item_'.$x.'");
                    function selector'.$x.'(){
                        if(item_'.$x.'Active == 0){
                            selectorReset();
                            item_'.$x.'.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
                            item_'.$x.'Active = 1;
                        }else{
                            selectorReset();
                            item_'.$x.'.style.backgroundColor = "";
                            item_'.$x.'Active = 0;
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            ';
            $x++;
        }
    ?>
    <script>
        var item = document.getElementsByClassName("area__item");
        function selectorReset(){
            for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){
                item[i].style.backgroundColor="";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </div>
    <style>
        .area{
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
            width:100%;
        }
        .area__item{
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
            height:5em;
            width:5em;
            border:1px solid black;
            margin:1em;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .area__item:hover{
            background-color:pink;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .area{
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
            width:100%;
        }
        .area__item{
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
            height:5em;
            width:5em;
            border:1px solid black;
            margin:1em;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .area__item:hover{
            background-color:pink;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="area">
    <?php

        $x = 0;
        while($x!=10){
            echo'
                <div id="item_'.$x.'" class="area__item" onclick="selector('.$x.')">
                '.$x.'
                </div>';
            $x++;
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <script>

        function selector(item) {

            // Get the total Class length

            var classLength = document.getElementsByClassName("area__item");

            // First check any of the classes holds the style attribute, then remove it

            for(var i = 0; i < classLength.length;i++){
                var element = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
                if (element.hasAttribute("style")) {
                   element.style.backgroundColor = "";
                }
            }

            // Get the selected element by argument
            // Then add classes to the selectedElement

            var selectedElement = document.getElementById('item_'+item);
            selectedElement.style.backgroundColor = "pink";

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution! but there is a new problem i am unable to de-select the item.

example: i click item 0 then item 1 (works as intended) then when i try to de-select item 1 it still remains selected as pink.

ill try to find a way around this later when i have time using your code as a base. thank you!